# failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found) angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I run the ng build --prod and moved the contents of dist folder on server sub folder, but its not working giving error "failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found) "

Here is error messages

```
polyfills.005087a1f7d36bd88778.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
inline.5a4ca7a5f1b2161e0aaf.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/styles.fe4393e6b8411da63d84.bundle.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.ff539f706c6b2bfd3e09.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
scripts.069cce74f9c8f7df78ea.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
polyfills.005087a1f7d36bd88778.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
scripts.069cce74f9c8f7df78ea.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.ff539f706c6b2bfd3e09.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.fe4393e6b8411da63d84.bundle.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Kindly help

Comment: What's not found?

Comment: bundles, I have  updated the error messages in question.

Comment: What's your server setup? There's a lot of information we need to begin suggesting solutions.

Comment: did you setup base url in your index page, so as it is matching to your server resource patch?

Comment: I have updated the base url and its working fine, thank you.